# How can I calculate "uncompressed" size for AWS Lambda?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-lambda-layers

I am trying to understand the deployment size limits for AWS Lambda as I encountered the following error after adding another layer to my Lambda function:

```
An error occurred: <function name> - Function code combined with layers exceeds the maximum allowed size of 262144000 bytes. The actual size is 269081659 bytes. (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException; Request ID: <request ID>; Proxy: null).
```

I understand that the total uncompressed size of code + layers cannot exceed 250 MiB but I cannot understand how my code and layers have breached that limit. I especially cannot make my layers add up to the 'actual size' stated in the error.

I am using the Java 8 runtime and my jar is 54 MiB. Unzipped it is 140 MiB. I had two existing layers with the following sizes:

| Layer | Compressed size | Uncompressed size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Elasticsearch (jar) | 22 MiB | 54 MiB |
| ImageMagick | 17 MiB | 58 MiB |

I added a further layer, Ghostscript, which is 16 MiB compressed and 34 MiB uncompressed. Adding this layer resulted in the error from above.

My confusion arises because I can't make any combination of the compressed/uncompressed files match the error message. Reviewing the output of `aws lambda get-function` shows the uncompressed sizes for the code and layers.

Additionally I deployed each of my layers individually and ran `df -h` in the Lambda instance to see how much space was being used. Layers are loaded to `/opt` and the size of this mount point was more or less equal to the uncompressed size for Elasticsearch and ImageMagick (within a megabyte or two, and possibly only different due to using MB and MiB inconsistently). However `df` reported that `/opt` was 52 MB when the Ghostscript layer was added which is almost twice as large as the uncompressed size on my machine. Even with these numbers I cannot find a combination that gives the the 'actual size' listed in the error.

How can I find out the actual space taken up by my code and layers?

---

Notes on calculating compressed and uncompressed size:

- For jar files I took the size of the jar file itself as the compressed size. For the uncompressed size I used the `unzip` command and used the size of the folder.
- For the layers I used the size of the zip file downloaded from the AWS console (which matched the output from the `aws lambda get-function` command) as the compressed size. For the uncompressed size I extracted the zip file and used the size of the folder.

Comment: How how you building and deploying this Lambda function. I have never seen an issue like that.

Comment: The Java code is a Maven project which uses the Shade plugin to include all the dependencies. To deploy I am using the Serverless framework. And for completeness the ImageMagick layer I am using is https://serverlessrepo.aws.amazon.com/applications/arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:145266761615:applications~image-magick-lambda-layer and the Ghostscript layer is https://serverlessrepo.aws.amazon.com/applications/arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:154387959412:applications~ghostscript-lambda-layer. Is there something in particular you are surprised by?

Comment: I was wondering if you were trying to deploy this Lambda function from an IDE. I typically build using Maven and deploy using the Lambda console. Never seen any issues as you are describing. I think there is a way for larger JAR or ZIP to updated via an S3 bucket using the Lambda console. Can you try that and see if you get better results.

Comment: Serverless framework does this already - it zips the jar and uploads it to S3. If it didn't and uploaded directly to Lambda I would expect it to fail as the jar is over 50MB.